# Can't find location and Alert dismiss automatic in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, cllocationmanager

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapKit: MKMapView!

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let myLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        mapKit.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.mapKit.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

This is my source code. and I'm Using Xcode 9 and swift 4.0

When I build and run, debug area print this "Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4", and Using GPS alert automatic dismiss. So I can't accept using GPS allow.

I also complete info.plist setting like this.

Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make CLLocationManager as global instance var  -

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mapKit: MKMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            let location = locations[0]
            let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
            let myLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
            let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
            mapKit.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            self.mapKit.showsUserLocation = true
        }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

This will prevent alert from dismissing automatically.

Comment: What's the difference? Declare in viewDidLoad

Comment: @usinuniverse, in viewDidLoad its scope is till that function. as soon as the function completed that property will be release. If property is release that means no one is owner to handle delegates now. 

If you declare globally your instance will be alive till the class is live.

Comment: @RishiChaurasia, Thank you So much. I understand it.